# jquery timepicker scroll time dropdown to current time

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

[I'm using this jquery time picker.](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/)

It is a very clean and efficient timepicker, but I am facing one problem, when I set this property...

```
{'scrollDefault': 'now'}
```

...to set the scroll position to local time if no value selected, it is not scrolling to the exact current time.

It doesn't make sense to show a time that has just recently passed. For example, if it is 10:19 AM, even though it is closer to 10:15 AM than it is to 10:30 AM, we don't want the top value in the dropdown list to be 10:15.

[Here is fiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/sona824/gpex91mk/1/)

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I know this has been a while but I came across this and I was wondering what the issue is as your time picker has the full range when I view it and it scrolls close to the current time. Do you need a closer step of options to select?

Comment: is there any solution to this problem ?